# Symfony Gedmo Translatable and YAML configuration for generating entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-extensions, stofdoctrineextensions

is it possible to use in a Symfony project Gedmo Doctrine Extension Translatable with YAML configuration and to generate the entities with `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities` ?

I tried the StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle, I tried Gedmo on its own. But I didn't get it working.

When I write the entities by hand and use annotations everything works fine.  But in my project every entity is defined by YAML.

Comment: How does your yaml file look? What error do you get?

Comment: I don't get an error. The PHP entities will not be generated with the Gedmo annotations.

Comment: Ahh, my yaml looks like the yaml in the docs. But before I will post code, I like to know if anyone got it working already or if it is not possible.